# OpenGL OES Iphone glCopyTexImage2D

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am new to openGL OES on iPhone and have a memory issue with glCopyTexImage2D. So far i understood, this function should copy the current framebuffer to the binded texture. But for some reason it always allocates new memory, which i can see in instruments checking the allocations.

My goal is to read texture images and draw on it, after drawing i want to save the new texture  , so i can scroll through the painting. So here is may code:

1) init opengl and framebuffer:

```
context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES1];

    if (!context || ![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:context]) {
        [self release];
        return nil;
    }

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);

    // Setup OpenGL states
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);


    CGRect frame = self.bounds;
    CGFloat scale = self.contentScaleFactor;
    // Setup the view port in Pixels
    glOrthof(0, frame.size.width * scale, 0, frame.size.height * scale, -1, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height * scale);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_DITHER);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Set a blending function appropriate for premultiplied alpha pixel data
    glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
    glTexEnvf(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES, GL_COORD_REPLACE_OES, GL_TRUE);
    glPointSize(64 / kBrushScale);
```

2) now i load the saved images into the framebuffer:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    // load texture
    NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    glGenTextures(1, &drawBoardTextures[i]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawBoardTextures[i]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, [data bytes]);

    // free memory
    [data release];
}
```

3) and finally render the texture:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

int width = 1024;
GLfloat quad[] = {0.0,1024.0,1024.0,1024.0,0.0,0.0,1024.0,0.0};
GLfloat quadTex[] = {0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,0.0};

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    quad[0] = width * i;
    quad[2] = quad[0] + width;
    quad[4] = quad[0];
    quad[6] = quad[2];
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawBoardTextures[i]);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, quad);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, quadTex);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

}
```

4) for now everything works fine, with gltranslatef i can scroll through the textures and also there is no allocation yet observed in instruments. so now i draw on the current window and want to save the result like followed:

```
        int texIndex = offset.x/1024;
    float diff = offset.x - (1024*texIndex);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);    
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawBoardTextures[texIndex]); 

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawBoardTextures[texIndex]);
    glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, diff, 0, 0, 0, 1024-diff, 1024); 
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, drawBoardTextures[texIndex + 1]);
    glCopyTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1024-diff, 0, diff, 1024);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glFlush();
```

No the problems starts. instead of writing it directly into the generated textures, it writes it into client memory. for every copied texture it uses ~4 MB of Ram, but every recopy doesn't need any memory. i really don't know what i did wrong.

Does anyone know what the problem is? Thanks alot for your help.

cheers

chris

Comment: Welcome to SO, I hope you've read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).